# Read csv data into columns same as csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I am trying to open this CSV file to then parse the data into columns. The problem is the way the data comes in is causing me problems. Wheni try to run a python script i get all the data in each sentence encclosed with a [' DATA HERE ']. I want to parse the data into columns like 'Account#', 'Service Address', 'City', etc. Just like the column names that are already in place below. The way this data is structured like i said is weird because it has column heads above and below. For example the column header 'Account #' has a second column header below as 'rate code'. Not sure the best way to go about this and would like to get some input from the experts.

Python Script

```
 import csv

with open('C:/Users/DEMO/Documents/statement-9-28-18.csv', 'r') as  csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

for line in csv_reader:
    print(line)
```

Result

```
['                                                  XYZ COMPANY                             DATE : 09/28/18         ']
['                                                                                                            PAGE :    1             ']
['                                                      ELECTRIC BILL STATEMENT                                                        ']
['                                                                                                                                    ']
['   CUSTOMER NAME:  XYZ CUSTOMER                            SUMMARY BILL NUMBER:  12345-67890        IF YOU HAVE ANY QUESTIONS,   ']
['                                                                  CUSTOMER NUMBER:      1111111        PLEASE CONTACT:              ']
[' MAILING ADDRESS:  4122 RICHARDSON ST                                                                                                 ']
['                                                                     BILLING DATE:     09/28/18        SUMB@XYZ.COM45               ']
['                   SANFORD             FL 32771                     PAST DUE DATE:     10/09/18        (305)333-3333                ']
['                                                                                                                                    ']
['                                                                                                                                    ']
['                                                                 READ   SVC B             MAXIMUM     TOTAL DUE  METER NO   REMARKS ']
['  ACCOUNT #  SERVICE ADDRESS                            CITY     DATE   DAY C    KWH        KWD        AMOUNT                       ']
['   RATE CODE CY CUSTOMER NAME                            MAILING ADDRESS                                                            ']
[' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ']
[' 11111-22222 485 JOHNSON AVE APT 1405                MIAMI    09/26/18  28 C       140                   29.11   BAT0123           ']
['  RS-1       XYZ COMPANY                             485 JOHNSON AVE                                                           ']
['                                                                                                                                    ']
[' 22222-33333 485 JOHNSON AVE APT 3541                MIAMI    09/26/18  28 C       130                   28.08   BAT0123           ']
['  RS-1       XYZ COMPANY                             485 JOHNSON AVE                                                           ']
['                                                                                                                                    ']
[' 33333-44444 485 JOHNSON AVE APT 4544                 MIAMI    09/26/18  28 C       172                   32.42   BAT0123           ']
['  RS-1       XYZ COMPANY                              485 JOHNSON AVE                                                           ']
['                                                                                                                                    ']
[' 55555-66666 485 JOHNSON ST AVE APT 1111                MIAMI    09/26/18  28 C       243                   39.81   BAT0123           ']
['  RS-1       XYZ COMPANY                              485 JOHNSON AVE                                                           ']
```

Comment: This seems more like a fixed width file than a comma seperated file. Have you tried using `pandas` python package?

Comment: If i use Pandas python package what character will i use to tell it that it is a seperate column? In the data one column is  '11111-22222' and second column is '485 johnson ave apt 1405'. There is only a space in between them. A lot of tutorials i am seeing have at least a comma that seperates them.

Comment: You call it a `line`, but what is returned by a `csv.reader` is not a string, it's a list of strings.  In your case (no commas in your NOT-COMMA Separated Values file) the list of strings contains a single string, i.e., a whole input line and so that is what you see when you `print(line)`, a list containing a single string.

Comment: is there anything i can do to seperate them into columns or seperate strings?

Comment: Can you upload your csv file somewhere to test it with pandas, i'm sure pandas will sort it out.

Comment: _"Is there anything i can do to sep[a]rate them into columns or sep[a]rate strings?"_ Yes, you could count the characters in the different fields of the different rows (when I say "you count" I mean _you count_ with a ruler or what else) and assign to the variables that you want to use appropriate substrings of each input line.  It's not a business for a `csv.reader`, you have to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**:  I want to parse the data into column

---

> **Note**: The simple `regex` will split on `-` and `/` also. If you expand the `regex` to your needs, this could be avoided.

```
import re

rc = re.compile(r'(\w+)')

with open('C:/Users/DEMO/Documents/statement-9-28-18.csv', 'r') as  itxt:
    for n, line in enumerate(itxt.readline(), 1):
        # Row 13 and 14 hold the Header
        if n in [13, 14]:
            findall = re.findall(rc, line)
            print("{}".format(findall))

        if n >= 16 and n%3 > 0:
            findall = re.findall(rc, line)
            print("{}".format(findall))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> ['ACCOUNT', 'SERVICE', 'ADDRESS', 'CITY', 'DATE', 'DAY', 'C', 'KWH', 'KWD', 'AMOUNT']
> ['RATE', 'CODE', 'CY', 'CUSTOMER', 'NAME', 'MAILING', 'ADDRESS']
> ['11111', '22222', '485', 'JOHNSON', 'AVE', 'APT', '1405', 'MIAMI', '09', '26', '18', '28', 'C', '140', '29', '11', 'BAT0123']
> ['RS', '1', 'XYZ', 'COMPANY', '485', 'JOHNSON', 'AVE']
> ['22222', '33333', '485', 'JOHNSON', 'AVE', 'APT', '3541', 'MIAMI', '09', '26', '18', '28', 'C', '130', '28', '08', 'BAT0123']
> ['RS', '1', 'XYZ', 'COMPANY', '485', 'JOHNSON', 'AVE']
> ['33333', '44444', '485', 'JOHNSON', 'AVE', 'APT', '4544', 'MIAMI', '09', '26', '18', '28', 'C', '172', '32', '42', 'BAT0123']
> ['RS', '1', 'XYZ', 'COMPANY', '485', 'JOHNSON', 'AVE']
> ['55555', '66666', '485', 'JOHNSON', 'ST', 'AVE', 'APT', '1111', 'MIAMI', '09', '26', '18', '28', 'C', '243', '39', '81', 'BAT0123']
> ['RS', '1', 'XYZ', 'COMPANY', '485', 'JOHNSON', 'AVE']
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***